# Getting an error when I try to import a loaded vector file to the QGIS GRASS Plugin

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, error

I am getting an error code when I try to import a contour line vector file GRASS via QGIS.  I have been trying to create a DEM from the contour lines following this tutorial:
http://linfiniti.com/2010/12/3d-visualisation-and-dem-creation-in-qgis-with-the-grass-plugin/

When I try to import the loaded vector (v.in.ogr.qgis) I get the following error message:

> v.in.ogr "dsn=C:\GIS\Elevation\Florida Counties\Bradford\Bradford.shp" output=BradfordGrass2 snap=-1 min_area=0.0001 -o
>
> Datum not recognised by GRASS and no parameters found
>
> Over-riding projection check
>
> Layer: Bradford
>
> DBMI-DBF driver error:
>
> Unable to create table: 'create table BradfordGrass2 (cat integer, FNODE_ double precision, TNODE_ double precision, LPOLY_ double precision, RPOLY_ double precision, LENGTH double precision, TOPO5_ double precision, TOPO5_ID double precision, CONTZ integer, CARRYZ integer, ELEV integer, WMD varchar ( 6 ), ADD integer)'
>   Finished with error

I am using five-foot contour lines downloaded from downloaded the data from the FGDL.

http://www.fgdl.org/metadataexplorer/explorer.jsp

Any suggestions as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the column name "ADD" is making trouble?